# How to use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes function ? php

Tags: php, cryptography, token, php-openssl

I want to generate token , to use it as sign in auth, so I want to assure that the token algorithm is cryptographically strong !

I am using this block of code to to achieve that :

```
$crypto_strong = false;
while($crypto_strong !== false)
$openssl =openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128,$crypto_strong);
$token = bin2hex($openssl);
```

is that correct ?

Comment: Your code is completely broken. Your loop will never run, and `$openssl` will never be set. You should at least be checking `$crypto_strong !== true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php), it describes the `$crypto_strong` parameter as:

> If passed into the function, this will hold a boolean value that determines if the algorithm used was "cryptographically strong", e.g., safe for usage with GPG, passwords, etc. **TRUE** if it did, otherwise **FALSE**

The value of `$crypto_strong` is going to be fixed for a particular system. So if your system doesn't use a strong algorithm, your code will enter an infinite loop.

According to those same docs, "*it's rare for this to be FALSE, but some systems may be broken or old*". So it sounds like you are unlikely to encounter may examples of a false value. Perhaps in those situations, it would be more appropriate to abort the procedure and present an error to the user.

I wasn't entirely clear on your background use case, so I've no idea whether this general approach is correct for you. But certainly your posted code is wrong.